# C# How to define new pointer struct?

Tags: c#, c++, struct

This structure is define at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
typedef struct _FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER {
  ULONG     ReplyLength;
  ULONGLONG MessageId;
} FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER, *PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER;
```

I defined it in `C# code` as below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER {
      public uint replyLength;
      public ulong messageId;
};
```

I only define **FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER** in `C# code`, **PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER** isn't.

How should I do to define **PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER**??

P/S: I want to define **PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER** to use this struct in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to (can't) define `PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER`.  Just specify it as either `out` or `ref` as appropriate.

```
[DllImport("foo")]
void SomeMethod(ref FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER lpMessageBuffer);
```

If you are specifically interested in `FilterGetMessage`, I'm not sure what if any dll it is exported from, but one possible signature would be as below:

```
[DllImport(fltmgr, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true, PreserveSig=false)]
void FilterGetMessage(
    CommunicationPortSafeHandle hPort, 
    ref FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER lpMessageBuffer,
    uint dwMessageBufferSize,
    IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

I used `PreserveSig` to automatically translate the `HRESULT` to an exception in the event of failure, the `CharSet` specification is defensive and results in the need for `ExactSpelling`.  `CommunicationPortSafeHandle` would be a class which inherits from [`SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandleminusoneisinvalid(v=vs.110).aspx) based off of [the documentation on `FilterConnectCommunicationPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540460(v=vs.85).aspx).

You would use this signature as:

```
FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER header;
FilterGetMessage(hFilter, ref header, 
    Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER)), IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: This is FilterGetMessage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). **`PFILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER`** is its parameter's type. Following you: If I change to C#, I just use **out `FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER`**. Is it right?